# Windows 8 preinstall downgrade to Win 7: UEFI problems :/

Tags: windows-7, windows, uefi, gpt

I have a friend who has a HP Laptop with UEFI booting. Due to some unfortunate human error resulting in an unbootable system, I suggested and he agreed to installing Win7 ("I hate the big tile thingys"). So I attacked with Gparted. Wiped the whole drive. Set flags to boot. Set part table as MBR.

However upon trying to install win7, it still claimed I had a GPT style disk. Unable to install. The only thing i can think of I'm doing wrong is not changing the BIOS/UEFI to legacy.

My question is, if I enable legacy, somehow get the drive to actually be MBR, and use my X86 DVD, should I be good? Is there some common glitches people miss when dealing with GPT/UEFI? I need some help because he now has a blank laptop which I am responsible for.

Another question. windows 8 came installed on a GPT disk. So why does it say it can't install to a GPT-style disk, when I boot the install DVD?

Backstory :  He locked himself out of windows 8 (forgot his password)... so he called me. Well, after trying to use the latest version of chntpw in UBCD5.2.6, i came to the conclusion i needed to wipe the drive and install windows 7. A little googling suggested using certain versions of chntpw, but i decided to not waste the time burning endless CDs.

Comment: Could you re-word you question there is a lot of flush in there and you will find a lot of people will ignore the question based upon this for more information on how to ask good question please see this link [ask]

Answer (score -1):

1. Windows 7 can use UEFI and GPT-style disks. Why bother going back to MBR? For this, you need a 64-bit version of windows. If you really do want to use MBR, then nothing much to take care of, except the 4 partition rule (primary/extended/logical partitions issue).
2. The reason Windows is saying it can't install to GPT is because it has been booted in BIOS mode. To boot a DVD in UEFI mode, you'll have to choose to boot from the DVD from an entry prefixed as 'UEFI: SlimType Optiarc ... '. NOT the 'CDROM: ...' or 'P3: ...'. Windows cannot install to GPT in BIOS mode.